# Unable to change display settings

Tags: configuration, ati, display

I have 2 displays and used to have 1 big desktop.
Now after the last upgrade, my custom settings are not used anymore and 
I cannot change them using the gnome-display-properties.

1. The mirror function keeps being
   active even when I un-select it.
2. The detect screens function doesn't do anything.
3. xorg.conf is missing in /etc/X11.

What could be the cause of this unwanted behaviour?

extra info:

```
$ uname -a
Linux fornost 2.6.35-20-generic #29-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 3 14:55:28 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lspci | grep VGA
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc RV710 [Radeon HD 4350]

$ lsmod | grep radeon 
radeon           906842  3  ttm                    68180  1 radeon drm_kms_helper         32836  1 radeon drm                   206449  5 radeon,ttm,drm_kms_helper i2c_algo_bit            6208  1 radeon

$ dpkg -l *radeon*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Naam                                   Versie                                 Omschrijving
+++-======================================-======================================-============================================================================================
ii  libdrm-radeon1                         2.4.21-1ubuntu2.1                      Userspace interface to radeon-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  radeontool                             1.6.1-1                                utility to control ATI Radeon backlight functions on laptops
ii  xserver-xorg-video-radeon              1:6.13.1-1ubuntu5                      X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI Radeon display driver
un  xserver-xorg-video-radeonhd            <geen>                                 (geen beschrijving beschikbaar)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change with ati's propierty settings tool. It is on your settings menu.

Comment: He seems to be using the open source radeon driver.

Comment: I think not... because I do not use the proprietary drivers.. but the radeon drivers shiped with Ubuntu.